# Connect an Arduino Ethernet to localhost:8000

Tags: arduino, connection, webserver, apache2

I have an Arduino connected via Ethernet to my computer and a webserver is running on localhost:8000.

computer IP: 192.168.1.5
arduino IP: 192.168.1.6

The connection between Arduino and Computer is technically working and I even could establish a connection between the arduino and the computer on port 80 but when I start the webserver (it is a symfony project) and commandline confirms 'server running on localhost:8000' and try to connect to '192.168.1.5:8000' from the arduino it fails.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to link the IP and the domain 'localhost' - is so, where?

Thanks a lot and best regards,
Steffen

Comment: How are you connecting to the web server from the arduino? How does it fail? What happens if you connect to the web server from your PC? Another PC?

Answer (score -1):

Start the webserver with app/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000